# Technical Guidance to resolve WAS / Java - Private Key Issue

Tags: java, websphere, keystore, websphere-8, private-key

Goal :

Retrieve private key from the WAS Keystore (custom private key imported in WAS Console) in our java application to sign data.    Signed Data would be decrypted using the Public key which is been shared to the other applications.

How we have done in our current (which is NOT working,  Unable to generate or convert the Key to PrivateKey )

We were retrieving the Websphere KeyPair Object with help of KeyHelper API and got the `java.security.Key` Object from the KeyPair.

Link which we used to develop the code referring Knowledge Center 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rsec_sslretgenkeysetgrp.html

Code Snippet :

```
String keySetGroupName = "CMODSSOKeySet";
com.ibm.websphere.crypto.KeySetHelper ksh =     com.ibm.websphere.crypto.KeySetHelper.getInstance();
Map generationKeys = ksh.getAllKeysForKeySet(keySetGroupName);

Iterator iKeySet = generationKeys.keySet().iterator();

String keyAlias = (String)iKeySet.next();
Object keyObject = generationKeys.get(keyAlias);
```

Now after we got the `keyObject` as instance of `com.ibm.websphere.crypto.KeyPair` and when we retrieve the Private key from the `keyObject` as mentioned below we get `java.security.Key` Object but not the PrivateKey object.

```
java.security.Key privateKeyAsSecret = ((com.ibm.websphere.crypto.KeyPair)key).getPrivateKey();
```

We need to convert privateKeyAsSecret to PrivateKey and we tried in different ways which doesnt work.

Option 1 :

```
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpecPKCS8 = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(privateKeyContent.getEncoded()));
 PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpecPKCS8);
```

Option 2 :

```
X509EncodedKeySpec keySpecPKCS8 = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(privateKeyAsSecret.getEncoded()));
PrivateKey tempPrivateKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpecPKCS8);
```

Option 3 :

```
PrivateKey tempPrivateKey = (PrivateKey) ((com.ibm.websphere.crypto.KeyPair) key).getPrivateKey();
```

Option 4 :

```
String privateKeyContent = new String(privateKeyAsSecret.getEncoded());
privateKeyContent = privateKeyContent.replaceAll("\\n", "").replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "").replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpecPKCS8 = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(privateKeyContent));
PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpecPKCS8);
```

We were not able to generate or convert the Key to PrivateKey by the all above mentioned options.